# How to dynamically change vuejs Method based on route parameters?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I built a reusable component where a user can upload an image and store it in firebase storage. The problem is that my component needs to be able to reference the images in the database with a label that coordinates with the section being updated.

My problem is in my method when I name the location for the "downloadURL". In my code below, I create the variable "picName" and define it as the section name, followed by "imgUrl". But, when
I reference picName in the function, it's value becomes the downloadURL.

If my section name is "welcome", then I want the downloadURL saved as the welcomeimgUrl in the database. For "about", it would be aboutimgUrl, etc.

Here is my method:

```js
editImage() {
      this.performingRequest = true
      let rest = this.restInfo
      let section = this.section
      let picName = this.section + 'imgUrl'
      console.log(picName)
      if (this.image) {
        this.image.generateBlob(
          blob => {
            let downloadURL
            let rand = (Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 16) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 16)).toUpperCase()
            let picRef = fb.storageRef.child('sectionPics/' + rand)
            picRef.put(blob).then((snap) => {
              picRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
                console.log('File available at', downloadURL)
                let dct2 = {}
                dct2[picName] = downloadUrl
                console.log(dct2)
                fb.restCollection.doc(rest.id).update({
                  dct2[picName]: downloadURL
                })
              })
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.performingRequest = false
              this.image.remove()
            }, 2000)
          }
        )
      } else {
        
      }
    }
```

How can I change the db location of my downloadURL based on the name of my section being edited?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the map creation when updating the Firestore document. When you write a map with literal object notation the keys are taken as strings, regardless of variables defined with the same name. Instead what you expected to happen is that the key `picName` to become the `picName`  **value** instead of the string **picName**. See the example below for code wise explanation and a way to fix it.

```js
picName = "foo"
downloadUrl = "bar"
dct1 = { picName: downloadUrl } 
console.log(dct1) // => { "picName": "bar" } (key as string)

// Solution
dct2 = {}
dct2[picName] = downloadUrl
console.log(dct2) // => { "foo": "bar" } (key as variable value)
```

---

EDIT: The code changed in the call to firestore update is not syntactically correct. Once the hashmap is created it should be directly passed to the update method. See the code below:

```
let dct2 = {}
dct2[picName] = downloadUrl
fb.restCollection.doc(rest.id).update(dct2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... I think you are on the right track, but it's not quite working yet. I'm adding your code to the method in the question. dct2[picName]: downloadURL causes an unexpected error